# Where is App::Application.load_tasks defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-engines

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

Dummy::Application.load_tasks
```

Given the above when making an engine, this dummy application also loads the engines tasks located in /lib/tasks as well. How does it do this? I can't seem to find where load_tasks is defined or how it works..

Any advice would be great.

Comment: Hope this helps you. `Rails.application.load_tasks` is defined in https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/engine.rb#L458-L462

Comment: @Horacio Thx for the docs. However, I think you need to reference to a specific release branch cuz code in Master Branch always changes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type:

```
gem which rails
```

How is this? If you get /path/foo/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails.rb or something, find there.

```
find /path/foo/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib -type f | xargs grep load_tasks
```

Comment: why don't you include the output of that command, essentially grepping the rails file for load-tasks. I don't get any output from that. ~$ find /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin/rails -type f | xargs grep load_tasks
~$  <-- no output.  i.e. `grep 'load_tasks' \`which rails\`` no output